# Surface Pro 4 doesn't have Processor Power Management options

Tags: windows-10, power-management, microsoft-surface-pro

I just got a Surface Pro 4, and did all the latest updates (firmware updates and 1511).

I went into Power Options, created a "Power Saver" power plan, then went into advanced power options to adjust the processor power options (to limit it).

Unfortunately, they seem to have changed things around; I'm missing many of the advanced power options:

[image] 
[image]

Compared to my Surface Pro 2 (also running 1511), I'm missing many options; most notably the "Processor Power Management" options. You can see a sample [here](https://superuser.com/questions/565347/how-does-windows-limit-the-cpu-power-options-battery-saving).

Does anyone know how to get these options back? I'd like to be able to limit the processor when I activate the Power Saver plan.

Unfortunately, I didn't check if I had these options prior to updating.

Comment: I also miss them for my Atom based Win8.1 tablet. seams to be related to chipset drivers. Does your Surface have the fanless Core M cpu?

Comment: @magicandre1981 Do these devices support InstantGo/Connected Standby/Modern Standby? See [this chat discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26411681#26411681) and [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/1017646/337631)

Comment: @DavidPostill oh crap. It's an M3 core which Ive never had before. I never even thought that it might not be supported :/.

Comment: @DavidPostill mine is also a connectedstandby device and all seam to miss those advanced options

Answer (score 3):

If you apply a registry tweak described  in blog [Restore Maximum Power State to Surface Pro 4](http://www.littletinyfrogs.com/article/474688/Restore_Maximum_Power_State_to_Surface_Pro_4) from  FrogBoy, a new process power management will be available that you can set to max CPU to 99% to prevent the CPU from going into Turbo mode.

This is what needs to be added to the registry, the download provides this in a so called .reg file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; Adds the Max CPU % back to the processor setting in power settings.

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00\bc5038f7-23e0-4960-96da-33abaf5935ec]
"Attributes"=dword:00000002
```

Comment: The matching "Minimum processor state" is found at `...\PowerSettings\54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00\893dee8e-2bef-41e0-89c6-b55d0929964c`. I gave it the same treatment of Attributes=2.