# How to set a limit to the fans speed?

Tags: cpu, gpu, fan, noise

I have a laptop and it makes a lot of sound when there are many programs open.
When I am in class this is very annoying.

Is there a way I can set a limit to the fan's speed(CPU and GPU) and thus set a limit to the sound produced, so that when I am in class my computer doesn't get noisy.
And if the CPU or GPU usage would be high instead of using more of the CPU or GPU and speeding up the fans to cool them, my computer just slows down?

I know I can set the power plan to balanced, and select ECO mode in the dragon center, but this does not limit the noise of the fans.

I am not interested in changing coolers or replacing other units.

I have an MSI GS63VR7RF, 16gb ram, i7-7700, GTX1060.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the heat is generated by the CPU, then
instead of limiting the fans which is dangerous, an alternative solution would be
to limit the CPU very slightly. This wouldn't be noticeable, but make a difference.

Assuming you are on Windows 10:

- Open *Power Options > Change plan settings > Change advanced power settings*
- Open the branch of *Processor power management*
- Open *Maximum processor state*
- Change the relevant entry (or both) from `100%` to something like `97%`.

Comment: "Processor power management" is not there on my machine (Windows 10 Pro, 18362.356). Only "Desktop background settings", "Sleep", "Power buttons and lid", "Display" and "Battery". There doesn't seem to be anything there that would help reduce temperature (and thus fan noise). Anyone any idea?

Comment: @BlackShift: Better post a separate question. Include a screenshot of your settings and give details of your operating system and computer models.

Comment: This question got me my "Processor power management" back: https://superuser.com/questions/1017788/surface-pro-4-doesnt-have-processor-power-management-options

Answer (score -1):

Whether you **can** or not, you ought to consider whether you **should**.

The fans ramp up to keep the computer cool. If you artificially limit their speed, you will cause overheats & system lockups.

First thing to do is to strip & clean the machine - you should do that every 6-12 months anyway.
Dust causes airflow loss causes heat causes high speed fans.
If that's not enough, get a laptop pad with its own fans, to push more cool air into the machine.

Comment: Is there a way to limit the fans speed, so that when the fans reach this speed, all the computer processes just slow down, or are paused, so that the CPU/GPU usage is lowered and there is no overheating or noise made.
My laptop is not too noisy, when in balanced and ECO mode, but I just want to set a limit, so it won't get too noisy no matter what.
The reason I want this, is that if my computer gets too loud I wont be able to use it in class.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Also note that there are ways to keep a computer cool that don't involve running the fans at maximum speed (which wears them down and decreases their lifespan). Automatically throttle the CPU, for instance.