# Run shell script even in sleep mode?

Tags: linux, bash, linux-mint, shell-script, suspend

I want to create a script that logs the battery level and CPU load on a laptop, however I still want to log the battery level whilst in sleep mode. Is there any way to do this in Linux?

OS: LM 18.04 LTS
DE: Xfce

Computer specs: 10-12 year old laptop, it's pretty bad but fine for casual use: Celeron 900 2.2GHz, integrated graphics, 1366x768 display, 120GiB SSD; the model is something like Compaq Presario CQ56.

EDIT: I have a working script for logging battery level already which is this command:

```bsh
upower -i $(upower -e | grep 'BAT') | grep -E "percentage" | awk -F: '{ print $2 }' | tr -d ' %'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Sleep" is defined as ultra-low power usage: All subsystems get turned
>   off and consume extremely little power but can be woken up quite
>   quickly by an external event: lid open, power button, key press, WOL
>   packet, BIOS.

From https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/257048/run-at-command-when-computer-is-sleeping

This means that you cannot run a program while the computer is sleeping. You could wake it up every 5 or 6 minutes and log the battery, however, wakeup will deplete the battery faster.

Answer (score 0):

On `sleep mode` a computer won't be processing information, alas it won't run your script. You can check this amazing [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1017571/is-the-cpu-active-in-sleep-mode) by DavidPostill.

But you can log the battery just before going to sleep and then on wake up. For that you will need to add your script to `.../systemd/system-sleep/` and check you sleep hooks to run it depending on you distro flavor.