# Go to sleep without turning off the monitor

Tags: windows-10, video, sleep, tv

My computer monitor is a TV set, and when there is no incoming signal, the set turns off after 10 minutes or so. There is no setting to turn it off in the TV set's settings menu.

I want my PC to go to sleep and reap all of the benefits, but at the same time I want to keep sending some video signal to the TV set (e.g. a simple black screen) so that the set does not turn off and I don't have to reach for the TV remote every time I want to wake up the PC.

After a lot of googling, I could not find any answer.

Comment: Not possible. When a PC is in a sleep state there is no video signal.

Comment: @DavidPostill I know that what I want sounds crazy, but maybe (just maybe) there is a way to keep the graphics card working and sending a video signal to the TV set while in a sleep mode?

Comment: It **is not possible**. Please read my answer  [Is CPU active in Sleep mode?](https://superuser.com/a/1017580/337631). The computer is effectively turned off except for the very small amount of power required when in sleep mode. There is **no video signal**.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to output a signal from the Display-out ports or in fact any other port when the PC is in sleep.

As an alternative solution, I can only think of three things, none of which are simple enough to be worth the investment, by that I mean it's easier to just buy a new TV. But here they are:

1. An IR blaster that sends the same signals as your TV remote, thus keeping the TV alive.
2. Many TVs have secret settings, which can be accessed by pressing a combination of buttons, but this is TV specific, so your best bet is to search the model of your TV in google and type something like, hidden settings, secret settings or similar behind it.
3. Maybe an active display switch that could automatically switch between inputs, but you would still have to connect a video source to the other input, something like a raspberry pi that would display a black image.

But there is a problem with solution number 1 and 3, the back-light would stay on which wastes electricity, so it isn't really economical, at that point as I already said, you are just better of buying a new TV/Monitor...

Answer (score 0):

Like others said, you can't. However...

Most tv's have a setting which will let them turn on the moment they receive a video signal. So you only have to wake the pc.

From sleep mode it's just a matter of pressing a key, move your mouse or whatever. If your goal is to wake up the pc from hibernation mode you have several options:

1. check out your bios settings to wake up when pressing any key or moving your mouse.
2. check out the [possibilities for your pc for a wake on lan call](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/enable-wake-on-lan-windows-10/). You need to set up your pc off-course , and there are apps for your phone to get your pc to wake up.
3. set a scheduled wake up time